# Python/SQLite3 - Insert output into an existing table

Tags: python, sqlite

Alright team, so I'm having a hard time finding documentation/answers based off of my situation, and now I'm just spinning my wheels.

```
def main():
    Scrape("c:\source\list2.csv", "General_Availability")

# Create data
def Scrape(Passed_Link, Release):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("C:/source/Matts.sqlite3")
    c = conn.cursor()
    with open(Passed_Link) as f:
      for row in csv.reader(f):
        for url in row:
          r = requests.get(url)
          soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
          tables = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"})
          for rows in tables.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': Release})[0:1]:
            item = []
            for val in rows.find_all('td')[0:1]:
              item.append(val.text.strip())
          prurl = url[-6:]
          rows = [prurl, item, "Placeholder"]
          print (rows)
    for sqlrow in item:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO APP_devicefirmware VALUES (?)', rows)

main()
```

So when I do this, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in Scrape
  sqlite3.OperationalError: table APP_devicefirmware has 3 columns but 1 values were supplied`
```

Comment: Why don't you use `sqlrow`?

Comment: `item` gets reassigned to an empty list each time through the loop.

Comment: All the beautiful soup and requests code is irrelevant to the question. See [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to put all my code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rows` is one value. You'll have to provide each of the values stored in the list `rows` like so:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO APP_devicefirmware VALUES (?, ?, ?);', (rows[0], rows[1], rows[2])
```

Comment: I recieved error `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.` by running your code

Comment: What the error is telling you is that one of the values you have provided is not supported by sqlite. `item` is a list. You cannot store a list or array in sqlite. You have to somehow break it up or serialize it (turn it into a string).

Comment: Okay, thats another road block! Thanks for the help, have some +rep